# Creating documents does not work

Tags: bash, mkdir

Hello i am trying to generate folders and name them according to input parameters
What is wrong in this script ?

```
root=$1
clcount=$2
clstep=$3
delay=$4
dstep=$5

echo  $root
echo  $clcount
echo  $clstep
echo  $delay
echo  $dstep

echo creating docs

for dindex in {$delay..100..$dlstep}
  do 
     for cindex in {$clcount..1..$clstep}
     do
        fname=$cindex_$dindex
        rm -rf $fname
        mkdir $cindex_$dindex        
     done
done

echo All finished
```

The script wont create any folder..and it somehow does not concatenate the values of `$cindex` and `dindex` in a string.

Comment: The brace expansion only works with literal values, not variables. Use `seq` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make up your mind if it's `dstep` or `dlstep`.
2. From [this Bash pitfall](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D):

   > `for i in {1..$n}`
   >
   > The BashParser performs BraceExpansion before any other expansions or substitutions. So the brace expansion code sees the literal `$n`, which is not numeric, and therefore it doesn't expand the curly braces into a list of numbers. This makes it nearly impossible to use brace expansion to create lists whose size is only known at run-time.
   >
   > Do this instead:
   >
   > ```
   > for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do
   > ...
   > done
   > ```

   Or use `seq`.
3. Your script reads `$cindex_` as a variable with the name `cindex_`. You want `${cindex}_`.
4. Quote variables properly. It may not be crucial here, but in general. E.g.:

   ```
   mkdir "${cindex}_$dindex"
   ```
5. There is no shebang. It wouldn't matter if you sourced the script; but if you run it, there should be a shebang like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. Because of `$1`, `$2` etc. I guess the script is meant to be run.

Comment: But in my case `n` is an argument received from input.So  don't i need `i<=$n` ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian This syntax of `for` doesn't need `$`. Just try it.